# How to implement extracting/subsetting ([, [<-, [[, [[<-) functions for custom S3 classes?

Tags: r, oop

I have a custom S3 class `foo`, which adds some custom behavior on top of a normal `data.frame`:

```
foo_object <- data.frame()
class(foo_object) <- c("foo", "data.frame")
```

For this class there should also be a list class `foo_list` to store many of these `foo` objects.

```
foo_list_object <- list()
class(foo_list_object) <- c("foo_list", "list")
```

If you apply a subsetting operation for multiple elements on a list like this via `foo_list_object[c(1,2,3)]` you get an object only of class `list`. But I want it to remain a `foo_list`.

Hadley [says](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) you should implement custom accessor functions for vector classes to achieve this behavior:

> When implementing a vector class, you should implement these methods: length, [, [<-, [[, [[<-, c. (If [ is implemented rev, head, and tail should all work).

My question concerning this has three parts:

1. What's the best way to implement custom accessor functions for S3 classes? Can I rely on the underlying primitive class?
2. Which accessor functions do I need in my case? I think I don't need to define `[[`, `[<-`, `[[<-` or `$` because in these cases the inherited functionality of `list` behaves correctly also for `foo_list`. Should I implement them anyway?
3. How can I implement an operator with 3 arguments like `[<-` or `[[<-`? You need the object, the index and the new value?

The following code for `[` seems to work:

```
`[.foo_list` <- function(x, i) {
  class(x) <- "list"
  as.foo_list(x[i])
}
```

This on the other hand doesn't:

```
`[[<-.foo_list` <- function(x, i, y) {
  if (!is.foo(y)) {
    stop("Please provide an object of class foo.")
  }
  x[[i]] <- y
}
```

How can I fix this (1./3.) and do I even have to (2.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the best way to implement custom accessor functions for S3 classes? Can I rely on the underlying primitive class?

Yes, you can. Call `NextMethod`, inside your `[<-.foo_list`, and wrap the result in your class as needed.

> Should I implement [all accessors] anyway?

If you want their result types to be `foo_list` or need to check the argument types, then yes, you need to implement the assignment accessors (but see below). You do *not* need to override the element read accessors (`[[`, `$`), unless you want to change their semantics: they inherit the correct behaviour from the `list` class.

> How can I implement an operator with 3 arguments like `[<-` or `[[<-`?

Essentially like you’ve done. You only need to adjust the parameter names: the new value parameter needs to be named `value` because R internally calls the function with a named argument. And your last line would lead to an infinite recursion — you need to either `unclass` `x` first, or use `NextMethod`:

```
`[[<-.foo_list` <- function(x, i, value) {
  stopifnot(is.foo(value))
  NextMethod()
}
```

This works, and preserves the class type of `x`. Note that the only reason to implement this method is to perform the check in the first line. If you don’t need this check, you don’t need to implement the method at all.

In a similar vein, for your `[` operator, the following simpler implementation works:

```
`[.foo_list` <- function(x, i) {
  as.foo_list(NextMethod())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very fast and comprehensible answer!