# How to I write an S3 extract method [ in r

Tags: r, data-extraction

I have a data frame called gfe_obj with structure as follows:

[image]

And I want to write an extract function such that when I run the code below, I get the corresponding output:

[image]

Currently, I have:

```
str(gfe_obj)
'[.gfe_obj' <- function(x,i) {
  class(x) <- "gfe"
  as.gfe_obj(x[i])
}

sub_gfe_obj <- gfe_obj[1:3]
str(sub_gfe_obj)
```

But when I run this code, I get Error in as.gfe_obj(x[i]) : could not find function "as.gfe_obj".

I referenced the method to write from here : [How to implement extracting/subsetting ([, [<-, [[, [[<-) functions for custom S3 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207515/how-to-implement-extracting-subsetting-functions-for-custom-s)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact structure of your `gfe` class is supposed to be, but assuming it is a list consisting of two objects (a 3D array called `frames` and a data frame called `info` with the same number of rows as the third dimension of `frames`, then your S3 method would be:

```r
`[.gfe`<- function(x, i) {
  x$frames <- x$frames[,,i]
  x$info   <- x$info[i,]
  x
}
```

To test this, I need a mock class constructor and some dummy data:

```r
gfe <- function(frames, info) {
  structure(list(frames = frames, info = info), class = "gfe")
}

gfe_obj <- gfe(frames = array(1:90, dim = c(3, 3, 10)), 
               info   = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10]))

str(gfe_obj)
#> List of 2
#>  $ frames: int [1:3, 1:3, 1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ info  :'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ x: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>   ..$ y: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "gfe"
```

Now we can see the extractor method works as expected:

```r
sub_gfe_obj <- gfe_obj[2:3] 

str(sub_gfe_obj)
#> List of 2
#>  $ frames: int [1:3, 1:3, 1:2] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
#>  $ info  :'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ x: int [1:2] 2 3
#>   ..$ y: chr [1:2] "b" "c"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "gfe"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, for some reason, I still get Error in as.gfe_obj(x[i]) : could not find function "as.gfe_obj" even though that code has been deleted already. I tried restarting my r but it doesn't work

Comment: @user19825372 my code is a full reprex. There is no point at which it looks for a function called `as.gfe_obj`. Also, your S3 class is called `gfe`, not `gfe_obj`, so your methods should end in `.gfe` not `.gfe_obj`